# Github comparing changes nothing to compare

Tags: git

So I'm trying to deploy an Angular app on to Heroku. I have done the following commands

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/pletheon/rockpaperscissors 
git add .
git commit -m "Upload files to Github"
git push origin master
```

When I go to the Github repository and compare the pull requests, it tells me "There isn’t anything to compare. main and master are entirely different commit histories."

Comment: Perhaps a naming mishap? GitHub is supposed to use ```main``` instead of ```master``` recently, if you're pushing to ```master```, you might get issues. Check GitHub, see what branches you have, or the branches that the repo you cloned from has.

Comment: Why did you add the remote? Was it not cloned from https://github.com/pletheon/rockpaperscissors initially? --- The repo has two branches `main` and `master`. Both are initial commits and they do not share a history.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I'm following a tutorial and the directions told me to do git remote add origin

Comment: The tutorial may not have been updated recently. Github now uses `main`, not `master` as the default branch. https://github.com/github/renaming

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have committed to the master branch directly.

I believe what you are trying to do is:

```sh
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/pletheon/rockpaperscissors
$ git switch -c feature/my-awesome-feature # <- apply changes away from master branch
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Upload files to Github"
$ git push
```

## Edit

> what does `git switch -c` means?

Creates a new branch **and** switches to it.

in the previous snippet a new branch has been created called `feature/my-awesome-feature`.

then all the working changes is added and committed to that branch.

after pushing to remote repo, you can open a new pull request normally where.

[image]

Comment: Github may still complain as the histories of master and main are unrelated.

Comment: So what should the base and compare be?

Comment: @BenjaminHeffner depends on whether you want to merge your feature branch into master or the other way around.

Comment: I want the master branch to merge on to the main branch

Comment: So how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @BenjaminHeffner Let's take a step back and see the big picture, you have one branch called "master" on github, and you are working on a new cool feature locally. the recommend way is for that new feature to have it's own branch (see line 2 in my sample). and after pushing, you will see a new branch on github. and PR would work fine. (base: master, compare: feature/my-awesome-feature)

Comment: Ok. So which branch do I switch to, the main branch or the master branch? (Sorry, I've used Git before, but I'm not very good with it)

Comment: @BenjaminHeffner it's ok :), i know git might look intimidating at first, but when you get the hang of it, it's fun. check my updated answer.

Comment: So would I do something like git switch -c rockpaperscissors?

Comment: @BenjaminHeffner sure, it can be anything